# MySQL Field bigger than bigint

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, architecture

Let's put the problem that way, I have a Pizza with 2 types of ingredientes. Those ingredients are sotred in an array in my PHP and in my MySQL I store an Int of the sum of the positions of these arrays in binary.

I mean:

```
$ingredients = ["cheese","pepperoni","bacon","onion"];
```

If my Pizza has Cheese and Bacon I store the value 2^0 + 2^2 = **5**.

What I achieve whith that is searching in my DB for all the Pizzas with value **5** and getting a quick and cool search.

My question is: What if I have a really big array of ingredients? Even if I only use 2 of them, if they are in the bigger positions of the array (let's say 100) I am screwed.

What kind of solution would you use in that particular problem?

P.D.- Obviously I'm not talking about a Pizza company, and I DO care about ms speed

Comment: [Please read this article](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/). You better make regular, related tables (pizza,pizza_ingredients,ingredients) before it's too late :)

Comment: Can't you ask for double cheese?

Comment: Sure, that's the solution I'm actually using, but I really love that kind of search by value I explained. It's a great solution for few values, but I was wondering about when large amount of them :-/

Comment: And no Álvaro, you can't (it totally fix in my structure) :-)

Comment: Not sure why I'd get a negative, but hey, I found "the answer" thanks to @Barmar :-)

Comment: -1 you are asking for help to drive in a screw with a hammer and you have turned down the kind offer of a screwdriver. I'm sure you aren't going to listen, but I'm hoping this comment will serve as a warning to anyone else who comes across your question and might think this is a "good idea".

Comment: I didn't turned it down, I was just asking about that SET type option :-( I know that's a correct approach to solve what I wrote (it's what I'm actually using), but I was asking for some other kind of approach involving bit operations. Maybe it's for a reason...

Comment: In the context of the question, there is no good reason. Perhaps you should have explained your real-world problem instead?

Answer (score 6):

You better make regular, related tables (`pizza`,`pizza_ingredients`,`ingredients`)

And that would be much much simpler for you and even MySQL:

```
# simple query to find pizza's with specified ingredients
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  pizza_ingredients tpzi
LEFT JOIN
  pizza tp ON
  tp.pizza_ID = tpzi.pizza_ID
WHERE
  tpzi.ingredient_ID IN (1,2,3,45)
```

Table examples:

Table `pizza`:

- pizza_ID, pizza_name

Table `pizza_ingredients`':

- pizza_ingredient_ID, pizza_ID, ingredient_ID

Table `ingredients`

- ingredient_ID, ingredient_name

---

What is interesting.. If you try to find pizzas with cheese:

Standard:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  pizza_ingredients tpzi
LEFT JOIN
  pizza tp ON
  tp.pizza_ID = tpzi.pizza_ID
WHERE
  tpzi.ingredient_ID = 1
```

Your idea:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  pizza
WHERE
  pizza_ingerdients MOD = 0
```

Will be slower :)

Comment: Thanks Peter, that would fit fine but my question is not looking for those kind of standar solution, I was looking for that bit wise solution

Comment: @JoseVillalobos this is standard solution because it's wise solution. You better use bitwise operators in some C code, not SQL

Comment: @Jose check my answer again. Your idea will be slower in many cases other than "find specific pizza"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's the way I'm actually handling it, but I was looking for some kind of bitwise operations. I will stay that way but keep looking for another solution, but anyway that bitwise solution will stuck at 64bits on MySQL

Answer (score 2):

In such a scenario, one should implement a many-to-many relationship between pizzas and toppings.

Comment: I know, but then I lose that part of the question: 

"What I achieve whith that is searching in my DB for all the Pizzas with value 5 and getting a quick and cool search."

Comment: @JoseVillalobos If you make website for pizza company do you care about ms speed?

Comment: It's a choice between maintainibility and ease of coding — and I would prefer the former. @Peter describes a good method to do as you say, but without confusing bit wise operators.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about the SET datatype. SETs are input and displayed as a comma-separated list of names, but they're stored internally as an integer bitmap, so searches are fast.

However, they're limited to 64 elements. If you need more than 64, you could have multiple columns: ingredients1, ingredients2.

Comment: +1 But you'd be doing the internet a favour by deleting this excellent answer ;-)